# How to make my links not to move when i change to different language?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, 960.gs

I have a small problem. This is the site I'm working on [My website](http://3pon.co.il/test/1/index.html)

My problem is that when I switch languages the links get disorganized.

How can i fix this?

Comment: Do you want them to remain in the same position? Then how about absolute positioning?

Comment: Looks like you forgot to close a tag. Your anchor exists outside of your li element on the other-language pages.

Comment: Whoops, almost gave the wrong the answer. @Torr3nt is right, you are 'leaking' some `a` tag.